# React - Replace value while iterating through nested json file (objects are not valid as a React Cchild)

Tags: json, react-native, object, types

I need to iterate a JSON object array and make some changes within it.
I have this (recursive) , but React does not like it;
The error is:
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

```
const changeVal = (data, oldV, newV) => {

    for(let i in data) {           
        if(typeof data[i] === 'object') changeVal(data[i], oldV, newV);
        if(data[i] == oldV) data[i] = newV
    }
    return data
}
```

How do I accomplish it?

Comment: can you console.log() the output of the function?

Comment: Thx, that got me on the right track, I tried to push a null as a newV where it matched the oldV.